# Xpath Sum NAN-Result - change empty cells to "0"

Tags: php, dom, xpath, sum, nan

I am trying to sum specific columns of a table using Xpath evaluate. It works great if all cells contain numbers. But as soon some cells of that column are empty, I'll get "NAN" as result. So, I really need a solution which handles empty cells `<td></td>` as a number or "0".

This is my current code, e.g. for column 4:

```
$file = $DOCUMENT_ROOT. 'URL';
        $doc = new DOMDocument;
        // load the document
        $doc->loadHTMLFile($file);
        $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
        print $xpath->evaluate('sum(//table[td/u/b/.="Contracts"]/tr[position() > 1]/td[4])');
        echo ' mio $</td><td>';
```

Index 4 (year 1) works. I want a solution for index 5 to 9 (year 2 to 6), where empty cells are to be expected for the forthcoming years. You can see that in the source html-file as well.

```
    <table>
<td align="center" colspan="1"><u><b>Contracts</b></u></td>
<tr><th>pos</th><th>player</th><th>age</th><th>year 1</th><th>year 2</th><th>year 3</th><th>year 4</th><th>year 5</th><th>year 6</th></tr>
<tr><td CLASS=tdp>PG</td><td CLASS=tdp><a href="IsaiahThomas18.htm">Isaiah Thomas                   </a></td><td>27</td><td>16.75</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td CLASS=tdp>PG</td><td CLASS=tdp><a href="DerrickRose365.htm">Derrick Rose                    </a></td><td>28</td><td>1.03</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td CLASS=tdp>SG</td><td CLASS=tdp><a href="DionWaiters14.htm">Dion Waiters                    </a></td><td>25</td><td>1.05</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td CLASS=tdp>SG</td><td CLASS=tdp><a href="EricGordon17.htm">Eric Gordon                     </a></td><td>28</td><td>2.10</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td CLASS=tdp>SF</td><td CLASS=tdp><a href="CarmeloAnthony90.htm">Carmelo Anthony                 </a></td><td>32</td><td>2.65</td><td>2.65</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td CLASS=tdp>SF</td><td CLASS=tdp><a href="TonyAllen25.htm">Tony Allen                      </a></td><td>35</td><td>10.50</td><td>10.50</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td CLASS=tdp>PF</td><td CLASS=tdp><a href="CodyZeller89.htm">Cody Zeller                     </a></td><td>24</td><td>2.65</td><td>2.65</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td CLASS=tdp>PF</td><td CLASS=tdp><a href="RichaunHolmes22.htm">Richaun Holmes                  </a></td><td>23</td><td>5.00</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td CLASS=tdp> C</td><td CLASS=tdp><a href="RudyGobert24.htm">Rudy Gobert                     </a></td><td>24</td><td>16.40</td><td>16.40</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td CLASS=tdp> C</td><td CLASS=tdp><a href="JahlilOkafor19.htm">Jahlil Okafor                   </a></td><td>21</td><td>1.10</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td CLASS=tdp>PG</td><td CLASS=tdp><a href="TyLawson99.htm">Ty Lawson                       </a></td><td>29</td><td>3.40</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td CLASS=tdp>SG</td><td CLASS=tdp><a href="JustinHoliday20.htm">Justin Holiday                  </a></td><td>27</td><td>1.60</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td CLASS=tdp>PG</td><td CLASS=tdp><a href="RonniePrice23.htm">Ronnie Price                    </a></td><td>32</td><td>1.80</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You need to show us some sample data. In particular, what exactly do you mean by "empty"? Also, the predicate `[td/u/b...]` looks wrong - a table does not normally have a td child.

Comment: Sure. I added the source code above. Can't change it, though. Have to work with this. Empty cells are here `<td></td>`